# Dart JsonSerializable with abstract class

Tags: flutter, dart, json-serialization

I'm trying to generate my json helper functions for an object, that contains a list with the type of an abstract class, like this:

```
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';

import 'exercise-variations.a.dart';

part 'routine.model.g.dart';

@JsonSerializable()
class Routine {

  List<ExerciseRoutine> exercises;

  Routine();

  factory Routine.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$RoutineFromJson(json);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$RoutineToJson(this);
}
```

```
    import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';
    import 'exercise-variations.a.dart';

    part 'base-exercise-routine.g.dart';

    @JsonSerializable()
    class BaseExerciseRoutine implements ExerciseRoutine {
      int sets;

      BaseExerciseRoutine();

      factory BaseExerciseRoutine.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$BaseExerciseRoutineFromJson(json);

      Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$BaseExerciseRoutineToJson(this);
    }
```

```
abstract class ExerciseRoutine {}
```

This way I get this error:

```
[INFO] Running build...
[SEVERE] json_serializable:json_serializable on lib/test/routine.model.dart:
Error running JsonSerializableGenerator
Could not generate `fromJson` code for `exercises` because of type `ExerciseRoutine`.
None of the provided `TypeHelper` instances support the defined type.
package:dojohub_app_flutter/test/routine.model.dart:11:25
   ╷
11 │   List<ExerciseRoutine> exercises;
   │                         ^^^^^^^^^
   ╵
[INFO] Running build completed, took 1.2s

[INFO] Caching finalized dependency graph...
[INFO] Caching finalized dependency graph completed, took 92ms

[SEVERE] Failed after 1.3s
pub finished with exit code 1
```

Which makes sense, because `ExerciseRoutine` does not implement a `toJson` function and a `fromJson` factory. Maybe I could add a `toJson` function to my abstract class but how do I fix the missing `fromJson` factory?

Answer (score 9):

I solved it by writing a custom fromJson and toJson function for the `exercises` Field

```
part 'routine.model.g.dart';

@JsonSerializable()
class Routine extends WorkoutRoutine {

  @JsonKey(fromJson: exercisesFromJson, toJson: exercisesToJson)
  List<ExerciseRoutine> exercises;

  Routine();

  factory Routine.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$RoutineFromJson(json);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$RoutineToJson(this);
}

List<ExerciseRoutine> exercisesFromJson(List<dynamic> json) {
  return json.map((e) {
    return BaseExerciseRoutine.fromJson(e);
  }).toList();
}

List<dynamic> exercisesToJson(List<ExerciseRoutine> exercises) {
  return exercises.map((e) {
    switch (exercises.runtimeType) {
      case BaseExerciseRoutine:
        return (e as BaseExerciseRoutine).toJson();
      default:
        return null;
        break;
    }
  }).toList();
}
```

Comment: This worked great for me, thanks! If you support different types of exercises in one list though, you'll want to use "switch (e.runtimeType)" instead.

Comment: You could use a JsonConverter() also! Have you considered it?

Answer (score 0):

In my project I had the similar issue, so I solved it this way:

Base class:

```dart
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';
import 'package:katharsis/core/api_services/api_date_formatter.dart';

enum MessageStatus { notSend, notViewed, viewed }

abstract class Message {
  final int id;
  final int userId;
  @JsonKey(name: 'date', fromJson: dateFromJson)
  final DateTime date;
  @JsonKey(name: 'out', fromJson: meFromJson)
  final bool me;
  final String? text;

  const Message({
    required this.id,
    required this.userId,
    required this.date,
    required this.me,
    this.text,
  });

  static bool meFromJson(int json) => json == 1;
  static DateTime dateFromJson(int json) =>
      ApiDateFormatter.convertFromTimestamp(json)!;
}
```

Inherited class:

```dart
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';
import 
part 'text_message.g.dart';

@JsonSerializable(fieldRename: FieldRename.snake)
class TextMessage extends Message {
  const TextMessage({
    required super.text,
    required super.me,
    required super.id,
    required super.userId,
    required super.date,
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My workaround was to use JsonConverter and handle each subclass seperately

```dart
class GeometryObjectConverter implements JsonConverter<GeometryObject, Map<String, dynamic>> {
  const GeometryObjectConverter();

  @override
  GeometryObject fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
    switch (json["type"]) {
      "circle" => Circle.fromJson(json),
      "dot" => Dot.fromJson(json),
      "line" => Line.fromJson(json),
      _ => throw UnimplementedError(json["type"])
    };

  @override
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson(GeometryObject object) =>
    switch (object.runtimeType) {
      Circle => (object as Circle).toJson()..["type"]="circle",
      Dot => (object as Dot).toJson()..["type"]="dot",
      Line => (object as Line).toJson()..["type"]="line",
      _ => throw UnimplementedError(object.runtimeType.toString()),
    };
}
```